# How to implement a carousel using ViewPager2 in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, carousel, android-viewpager2

I need to implement a carousel.I already followed the steps according to this reference.
[Android ViewPager(2) with dots indicator](https://medium.com/@adrian.kuta93/android-viewpager-with-dots-indicator-a34c91e59e3a). But I need an output like this. can anyone help me on this?
[image]